# decode Content-Type: text/enriched; to readable text

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, mime-types, decode

I need to parse `Content-Type: text/enriched;` email to readable text.

Such as:

```xml
<ParaIndent><Param>Out</Param><FontFamily><Param>Calibri</Param><FontFamily=
><Param>Symbol</Param>*</FontFamily><FontFamily><Param>Symbol</Param>      =
=20
```

to parse.

I have seen all the python email library, but there is no method to do this. Does anyone know how to decode this?

Comment: Can't use any `XML` ready to use module because got duplicated keys. Try `split` for headers and later `split` for values of course need create `String` proccessing. Maybe got short way with `re` but i haven't idea about this.

Comment: Not sure if it works but this might get you started: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576800-convert-textenriched-mime-to-texthtml/

Comment: seems not work, the main issue is to parse <ParaIndent><Param>Out</Param><FontFamily><Param>Calibri</Param><FontFamily=
><Param> this tags, do any one know use which application to open the file?